# How to display label of unnamed drive?

Tags: delphi, drives

I want to get the name or label of drive.

I use this function :

```
function GetVolumeLabel(DriveChar: Char): string;
var
  NotUsed:     DWORD;
  VolumeFlags: DWORD;
  VolumeInfo:  array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  VolumeSerialNumber: DWORD;
  Buf: array [0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
    GetVolumeInformation(PChar(DriveChar + ':\'),
    Buf, SizeOf(VolumeInfo), @VolumeSerialNumber, NotUsed,
    VolumeFlags, nil, 0);

    SetString(Result, Buf, StrLen(Buf));   { Set return result }
    Result:=AnsiUpperCase(Result)
end;
```

For example, here're my drives in Windows Explorer :

```
Local Disk (C:)
Data (D:)
DVD RW Drive (E:)
```

The output of the code :

```
C: 
D: DATA
E:
```

The labels of C and E are empty. What winapi/function should I use to display the label of unnamed drive (C and E)?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that "Local Disk" and "DVD RW Drive" are used for placeholders when there's no volume labels. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365248(VS.85).aspx):

> A label is a user-friendly name that
>   is assigned to a volume, usually by an
>   end user, to make it easier to
>   recognize. A volume can have a label,
>   a drive letter, both, or neither.

Not sure if this helps, but you might want to use [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939(VS.85).aspx) and generate the labels based on the return Value. While GetDriveType differentiates between hard drives, removable drives and CD type drives, I don't think it does not separate between CD-ROM/CD-RW/DVD-ROM/DVD-RW drives.